# How I can make method take infinity arguments in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to make method take infinity arguments in objective-c and add these arguments .

Comment: Pass a single argument of type `double`. Pass C99's `INFINITY` as the value. (attn: humorous comment)

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe `1.0 / 0.0` makes it C89-compatible :P

Comment: @H2CO3 That's depending on the architecture. C89 (IEEE 754) does not guarantee non-signalling division-by-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming by "infinite" you mean "as many as I want, as long, as memory allows".

Pass a single argument of type `NSArray`. Fill it with as many arguments as you wish.

If all arguments are guaranteed to be non-object datatypes - i. e. int, long, char, float, double, struct's and arrays of them - you might be better of with a `NSData`. But identifying individual values in a binary blob will be trickier.

Since you want to add them up, I assume they're numbers. Are they all the same datatype? Then pass an array (and old style C array) or a pointer, and also a number of elements.

EDIT: now that I think of it, the whole design is fishy. You want a method that takes an arbitrarily large number of arguments and adds them up. But the typing effort required for passing them into a function is comparable to that of summing them up. If you have a varargs function, `Sum(a,b,c,d,e)` takes less typing than `a+b+c+d+e`. If you have a container class (NSArray, NSData, etc), you have to loop through the addends; while you're doing that, you might as well sum them up.

Comment: Can you give me example using NSData by the way you explained ??

Comment: Not enough information for that. The NSData approach only makes sense if you have multiple *number* arguments of *different* numeric types. I don't know if that's the case.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible on a finite machine (that is, all existing computers).

If you're good with a variable, yet finite, amount of arguments, there are C's `...` [variadic argument functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C).